# View text in terminal with specific patterns highlighted

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, less

I want to view text (could be a file or a piped command output) in the terminal, but I would like to highlight a specific pattern in the text with colors, similarly to how `grep` highlights the pattern match in its output lines.

The reason why I can't use standard `grep "pattern" /path/to/file` here is because I want to view the entire text (ideally scrollable as if piped through `less`) and not just the lines containing the pattern.

Comment: `grep --color -E "test|$" yourfile`

Comment: Oops, sorry. Had a typo in it. It surprisingly works. Please post as answer @AndroidDev :)

Comment: Certainly! I'll also include sample output.

Comment: Too bad `less` seems to filter out the color escape codes, I can't pipe it through that without losing the highlighting. Or is it `grep` which detects that it gets piped and removes the color escapes itself?

Comment: I posted an answer. I think it would be `grep` removing the color, since if you pipe the output from that command to `grep` again, the previous highlighting is removed.

Comment: @ByteCommander try the `-r` or `-R` switch e.g. `grep --color=always -E "test|$" yourfile | less -R`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, that works. But it requires the `grep --color=always`, just `grep --color` is not enough.

Comment: @ByteCommander agreed - I don't think `--color` does anything in either case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, this can be done very easily with some `grep` parameters.

The magic command you are looking for is:

```
grep --color -E "test|$" yourfile
```

Here's some sample output:
[image]

---

**Full disclosure**: That command was taken from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/367).

Comment: You could include @steeldriver's approach to pipe it through `less` while preserving colors into your answer. And it would be nice to see an explanation of the command.

Comment: @ByteCommander - I'll do that a bit later this evening. Have to do something else ATM :)

Comment: It's basically matching a zero-length expression that occurs in every line; because it occurs in every line, every line is output; but because it has zero length, the match isn't highlighted. As well as `PATTERN|$` you could use `^|PATTERN` or even just `|PATTERN` (since the empty pattern matches all lines as well).

Answer (score 4):

If you're not stuck on *color* highlighting, you could use `less` itself e.g.

```
less +g -p PATTERN file
```

or

```
less +g +/PATTERN file
```

The `+/PATTERN` highlights all instances of `PATTERN` in `file`, and the `+g` suppresses the default behavior of scrolling to the first match.

Answer (score 1):

## Highlight multiple patterns, phrases with the colour of your choice:

You can save the following script in a file named `~/.rc_highlight_pattern_v0.4_rc` and source it using `source ~/.rc_highlight_pattern_v0.4_rc` (or you may edit your `~/.bashrc` file to include this sourcing).

Sourcing this script will avail `_Highlight_Pattern` function in the terminal. See `_Highlight_Pattern -h` for help.

```
## Script name: rc_highlight_pattern_v0.4_rc
## Script version: 0.4
## Script stats:
##   * No. of global variables ( 0* ) : { * there are three, but uset from scope at end }
##         3 (global destructed: __USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN_ENABLE ; __USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN_SHOW_INFO ; __USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN__SCRIPT_ARGS )
##       + 1 ( shell variables: REPLY )
##   * No. of external commands (which are not among Bash builtins): 1
##   * List of external commands: `sed'.

declare -g __USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN_ENABLE="YES"

declare __USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN__SCRIPT_ARGS=""
while [[ ${#} -gt 0 ]]; do
    __USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN__SCRIPT_ARGS="${1}"
    case "${__USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN__SCRIPT_ARGS}" in
        -i|--info)
            __USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN_SHOW_INFO="YES"
            shift
            ;;
        -n|--no-source)
            __USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN_ENABLE="NO"
            shift
            ;;
        *)
            break  ## stop parsing command-line
            ;;
    esac
done

unset __USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN__SCRIPT_ARGS

if [[ "${__USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN_SHOW_INFO}" == "YES" ]] ; then
    while read -r ; do
        echo "${REPLY}"
    done <<-__EOF
Description:
    This script will avail _Highlight_Pattern() function which can be used to
highlight patterns in the text being written to the stdout.

__EOF
fi

if [[ "${__USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN_ENABLE}" != "YES" ]] ; then
    return 0
fi

#### Definitions start:

function _Highlight_Pattern() {
    declare hl_color="red"
    declare -i case_insensitive=0

    declare output=""

    declare -A __color
    declare color_start=""
    declare color_end=""

    __color["black"]='\\033\[1;30m'
    __color["red"]='\\033\[1;31m'
    __color["green"]='\\033\[1;32m'
    __color["brown"]='\\033\[1;33m'
    __color["blue"]='\\033\[1;34m'
    __color["magenta"]='\\033\[1;35m'
    __color["cyan"]='\\033\[1;36m'
    __color["white"]='\\033\[1;37m'
    __color["nocolor"]='\\033\[0m'

    color_end="${__color["nocolor"]}"

    declare func_args=""
    while [[ ${#} -gt 0 ]]; do
        func_args="${1}"
        case "${func_args}" in
            -c|--color)
                hl_color="${2}"
                shift # shift past option
                shift # shift past arg
                ;;
            -i)
                case_insensitive=1
                shift # shift past option
                ;;
            --)
                shift
                break  ## stop parsing command-line
                ;;
            -h|--help)
                shift
                while read -r ; do
                    echo "${REPLY}"
                done <<-__EOF
Usage:
  ${FUNCNAME} [Options] [PATTERN]

Description: This function highlights the PATTERN in its input which is the
output of another command piped to this function.

Options:
  -c, --color color_name    Use 'color_name' to highlight pattern. If not used,
        the default color will be used. The available choices for 'color_name'
        are: black, red, green, brown, blue, magenta, cyan, white. The bright
        variant of the color will be used.
  -i    Use case insensitive search.
  -h, --help    Show this help.

Limitations: This function is not well tested and may fail at times; this is
experimental.

Examples:
  \`echo "A function to highlight pattern." | ${FUNCNAME} -c white -- highlight'
  \`echo "A function to highlight pattern." | ${FUNCNAME} highlight'

__EOF
                return 0
                ;;
            *)
                break  ## stop parsing command-line
                ;;
        esac
    done

    color_start="${__color[${hl_color}]}"
    if [[ -z "${color_start}" ]] ; then
        color_start="${__color["red"]}"
    fi

    if [[ ${case_insensitive} -eq 0 ]] ; then
        output="$( sed -r 's,('"${1}"'),'"${color_start}"'\1'"${color_end}"',g' )"
        shift
        while [[ ${#} -gt 0 ]] ; do
            output="$( echo "${output}" | sed -r 's,('"${1}"'),'"${color_start}"'\1'"${color_end}"',g' )"
            shift
        done
    else
        output="$( sed -r 's,('"${1}"'),'"${color_start}"'\1'"${color_end}"',ig' )"
        shift
        while [[ ${#} -gt 0 ]] ; do
            output="$( echo "${output}" | sed -r 's,('"${1}"'),'"${color_start}"'\1'"${color_end}"',ig' )"
            shift
        done
    fi
    echo -e "${output}"
}

unset __USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN_SHOW_INFO
unset __USR_shHIGHLIGHT_PATTERN_ENABLE
## End Of Script.
```

Example usage:

```
echo "Highlight words with colour of your choice, e.g. green." | _Highlight_Pattern -c green green
echo "A function to highlight word." | _Highlight_Pattern word
echo "A function to highlight phrase." | _Highlight_Pattern 'highlight phrase'
echo "A function to highlight pattern." | _Highlight_Pattern 'fun.*pattern'
echo "A function to highlight multiple words of your choice." | _Highlight_Pattern function highlight words
echo "Highlight multiple patterns with _Highlight_Pattern function." | _Highlight_Pattern 'H[^[:space:]]*' 'pa[^[:space:]]*'
echo "Use CaSe-Insensitive search." | _Highlight_Pattern -i 'case-insensitive'
PAGER= man bash | _Highlight_Pattern -i bash | less -R
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]