# highlighting specific lines in different colors when starting a scipt with printf

Tags: command-line, bash, colors

I am using a bash script. When I launch my script, how can I highlight specific lines on the output? For example, all lines with "Enable" should be green, all lines with "Disable" in red and all others yellow. Like this:

When I run it, I use:

```
YELLOW="\e[33m"
GREEN="\e[92m"
RED="\e[31m"
printf "${YELLOW}"
./config.sh --enable 1 2 3 4 5 --disable 6 7 8 9
```

With this, the output is yellow. That's OK, but how can I use  different colors on enable and disable lines?

The output looks like:

```
Enable 1
Enable 2
Enable 3
Enable 4
Enable 5
Disable 6
Disable 7
Disable 8
Disable 9
aaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccc
ddddddddddd
```

And then, after all lines with enable are in green and disable are in red, from `aaaaaaaaa` on, everything after that should be in the default yellow color. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View text in terminal with specific patterns highlighted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810288/view-text-in-terminal-with-specific-patterns-highlighted)

Comment: Specifically https://askubuntu.com/a/1502049/1004020

Answer (score 6):

If you insist on `printf` you can do it like this:

```bash
highlight() {
  YELLOW="\e[;33m"
  GREEN="\e[;92m"
  RED="\e[;31m"
  while read -r; do
    case "$REPLY" in
      *Enable*)
        printf "$GREEN%s$YELLOW\n" "$REPLY"
        ;;
      *Disable*)
        printf "$RED%s$YELLOW\n" "$REPLY"
        ;;
      \[????\]*)
        printf "$YELLOW%s\e[m%s\n" "${REPLY:0:6}" "${REPLY:6}"
        ;;
      *)
        printf "$YELLOW%s\n" "$REPLY"
        ;;
    esac
    printf "$YELLOW"
  done
}

# ./config.sh --enable 1 2 3 4 5 --disable 6 7 8 9 |& highlight
highlight < <(setsid ./config.sh --enable 1 2 3 4 5 --disable 6 7 8 9 2>&1 </dev/null)

export CLICOLOR=0
highlight < <(setsid cmake --build ./path/to/build 2>&1 </dev/null)
```

[image: example output]

This just reads each line and adds the correct coloring before printing it. The `|&` captures stderr as well. [@rusty's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1502049/1004020) would be more general but it uses sed. The resets, the `$YELLOW` at the end, and the `setsid` are many workarounds for some strange behavior from the `./config.sh` script.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151729/discussion-on-answer-by-daniel-t-highlighting-specific-lines-in-different-colors); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

it worked for the percentage, but anything else was in grey. but i have managed to get it work for cmake, based on your advice:

```
highlight() {
  YELLOW="\e[;93m"
  GREEN1="\e[;32m"
  GREEN2="\e[;92m"
  MAGENTA="\e[;95m"
  STOP="\e[0m"
  while read -r; do
    case "$REPLY" in
      *NEON*)
        printf "$GREEN2%s$YELLOW\n" "$REPLY"
        ;;
      *Scanning*)
        printf "$MAGENTA%s$YELLOW\n" "$REPLY"
        ;;
      \[????\]*Building*)
        printf "$YELLOW%s\e[$GREEN1%s\n" "${REPLY:0:6}" "${REPLY:6}"
        ;;
      \[????\]*Linking*)
        printf "$YELLOW%s\e[$GREEN2%s\n" "${REPLY:0:6}" "${REPLY:6}"
        ;;
      *)
        printf "$YELLOW%s\n" "$REPLY"
        ;;
    esac
done
  printf "$STOP"
}
```

with this, cmake has all the default colors via printf. the percentage, which default is grey, now has yellow and the built line after the percentage ist also in yellow, which also is default in grey. anything else of the cmake output, has the colors, which cmake also have without printf. thanx for your help :)

the other one, with enable and disable, was for something else. not for cmake.